# Track use of an access database

Tags: database, ms-access

Hi i have an old project which uses an MS-Access file as DB. I want to track its use for a performance assessment. It is accesses via a remote drive added to all hosts that use the application. How can I track the access to the file?

The "server" is a windows 2000 machine. The file is access 97 and its just a back end.

I want to know when a computer is accessing it and when, so i can track how many times it had been open per day per hour, also how many user are accessing it at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to know? Which computers are accessing the database? Which users are using it? How many times they open it per day? How many times they use it per day?

Comment: Is the Access DB just a back end or is the front-end also in that DB? Also, what exactly do you want to track?

Comment: Also, what version of Access?

Comment: how many computers are accesing it and when. How many concurrent users are over it. Its an acces 97 backend. Thanks.

Comment: still need to know whether the front end is in the same DB or not. If not, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: the application uses directly the remote DB so all users are connected to it, i hope this clarifies the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to put code in the application code/front-end to keep track of it.

You might be able to write a program to watch the LDB file and record activity, but it wouldn't be trivial and even if it works, it is unlikely to be completely accurate.

Not a great answer, but Access isn't a client-server DB (as a back-end) so your options are limited.

Comment: Will get some info from the app but also will use some of the info of the LDB file. I understand i can get the user and pc name of those connected to the file, but i dont clearly undesrtand if those are the "current logged users". It will be ok if i get approximated results. Thanks.

Comment: The LDB file isn't super reliable, in my experience. It is mostly used internally by Access for locking the DB and there are a lot of ways that records can get orphaned and left in that file even when they are no longer using the app. This will be doubly true if you have something reading from it that might lock it when the Access wants to delete it. Proceed with cauion.